# Best way to get the count of data in big data table using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 12 millions of data and I want to get a count of data which matches my criteria.  Table is well indexed and when I want to test the worst case of get the count of all the records in table will take hours to get the data using

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM big_table 
WHERE date > xxx  
  AND date < yyy
```

Does anyone have any better idea to get the count in java using SQL?

Comment: Are you sure that `date` is indexed? What is the type of `date`?

Comment: update your question adding the table schema.. with the related  indexes ..and a real code sample of your query ..(not xxx and yyy)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @RichardSchneider : Yes date is a timestamp column and it is indexed.

Comment: Then show explain output pls.

Answer (score 0):

I am investigating the very same problem and I've found a possible solution in this article:

https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#dup_counts

The suggested solution is **Postgres specific** and provides an **estimation of the rows affected by a specific query** - not the exact count.